# What does the unit M stand for?

Tags: concentration, notation, units

What does $\mathrm{M}$ signify in this pH calculation? To me, it just seems to be a random variable.

For example: $\ce{[H+]} = 1.0\times10^{-7}~\mathrm{M}$

I am not sure what the $\mathrm{M}$ is supposed to mean?

Comment: M = Molarity = mol per Liter of solution

Answer (score 6):

It is shorthand for molarity. More precisely the amount concentration. It is used as a unit and stands for mole per litre.

The [IUPAC gold book writes](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00295.html):

> **amount concentration,**
>   Amount of a constituent divided by the volume of the mixture. Also called amount-of-substance concentration, substance concentration (in clinical chemistry) and in older literature molarity. For entities B it is often denoted by $\ce{[B]}$. The common unit is mole per cubic decimetre ($\mathrm{mol\, dm^{-3}}$) or mole per litre ($\mathrm{mol\, L^{-1}}$) sometimes denoted by $M$.

In your example it just means the concentration of protons in solution is $\ce{[H+]} = 1.0\times 10^{-7}~\mathrm{mol/ l}$.

Comment: Martin, thanks. What do protons have to do with this considering this is regarding PH. Also, you have "mol/1" so meaning mole per 1 what exactly?

Comment: @Atticus283blink Please read the [Wikipedia page on pH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH) it answers all your questions. Please also read the answer carefully, it's states multiple times that it is mole per litre. The unit litre may be written as L or l.

Comment: "mol/l" is *mole(s) per liter* He used a lowercase l instead of the uppercase L.  //  On old typewriters there was no digit 1. you were expected to use the lowercase L. Most typefaces now try to have somewhat different forms for the digit 1 and the lowercase letter L. The digit 0 and the uppercase letter O are another problem.