# What is the difference in mosM and mOsm units, if there is any at all?

Tags: terminology, units, osmosis

I'm reading Agre's paper on aquaporins [[1](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.256.5055.385)] and he uses a unit called "mosM" throughout the paper, for example:

> … ocytes were transferred from 200 mosM to 70 mosM modified Barth's buffer.

I just want to understand what this unit means, is it the same as mOsm? I know this might be an very stupid question but hey, I'm only a undergrad.

#### Reference

1. Preston, G. M.; Carroll, T. P.; Guggino, W. B.; Agre, P. Appearance of Water Channels in Xenopus Oocytes Expressing Red Cell CHIP28 Protein. *Science* **1992**, 256 (5055), 385–387. DOI: [10.1126/science.256.5055.385](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.256.5055.385).

Comment: Remember that "paper never refused ink". Having a wrong notation in *Science* magazine does not endorse its correctness.

Comment: @M.Farooq It's not just *Science*, *Nature* uses this symbol too: https://doi.org/10.1038/46045.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the following table consisting of compiled notations presented in offline edition of *The ACS Style Guide* and *AMA manual of style*, section *13.12 Units of Measure*:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\hline
\text{Unit of measure} & \text{Symbol} & \text{Ref.} \\
\hline
\text{osmolar} & \text{osm (also osM, Osm)} & \text{[1, p. 191]} \\
\text{osmole} & \text{osm} & \text{[2, p. 635]} \\
\text{microosmole} & \text{µOsm} & \text{[2, p. 634]} \\
\text{milliosmole} & \text{mOsm} & \text{[2, p. 634]} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

symbols $\pu{Osm}$ and $\pu{osm}$ refer to the *amount-of-substance* of an osmotically active entity, and symbol $\pu{osM}$ refers to osmolar *concentration* suggesting the following relation:

$$\pu{1 osm L^-1} = \pu{1 Osm L^-1} = \pu{1 osM}$$

The letter “o” in $\pu{Osm}$ appears to be capitalized for the sake of better readability when used in conjunction with metric prefixes, and the letter “m” in in $\pu{osM}$ is likely capitalized to resemble analogy with the [unit symbol for molarity](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/115201/41328) (small capital letter “m”: ᴍ).

#### References

1. *The ACS Style Guide: Effective Communication of Scientific Information*, 3rd ed.; Coghill, A. M., Garson, L. R., Eds.; American Chemical Society; Oxford University Press: Washington, DC; Oxford; New York, **2006**. ISBN 978-0-8412-3999-9.
2. *AMA Manual of Style: A Guide for Authors and Editors*, 11th ed.; American Medical Association, Ed.; Oxford University Press: New York, **2020**. ISBN  978-0-19-024656-3.

Comment: Does the ACS Guide say anything about the osmolality? IUPAC still has this term with a different notation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please correct me if I'm wrong, it is the same as in 1mol/L = 1M, hence 1osmol/L=1osM?

Comment: @M.Farooq No, the third edition of the ACS Style Guide doesn't mention osmolality. [Good point regarding IUPAC though](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/O04340).

Comment: @RafaelFranco Yes, this would be my interpretation. Minor correction: don't forget to put a space between the numerical value and the unit symbol.

Answer (score 5):

I think the clinical chemistry notation has not been standardized but certainly it has been inspired by chemists.

The capital M in mosM emphasizes that it is millios*M*olar. Chemists use capital M to denote molarity.

On the other hand, mosm indicates millios*m*olal. Chemists use small m to symbolize molality.

This notation is not universal.

From this slightly dated article on Osmolality, which is behind pay-wall
[Osmolality, Harry F. Weisberg Laboratory Medicine, Volume 12, Issue 2, 1 February 1981, Pages 81–85](https://academic.oup.com/labmed/article-abstract/12/2/81/2640857).

> #### Terminology and Units
>
> In 1934, Gamble, et al.,<sup>11</sup> introduced the term ”osmillimole” which has been successively transformed into mosM (milliosmolar), mosm (milliosmolal), the noncommittal mOsm, and the present-day mosmol (milliosmole). Raoult’s law states that the lowering of the vapor pressure (one of the four ”colligative”
> properties of dilute solutions) is proportional to the mole-fraction (more easily calculated from molality) of solute present in the mixture.